# In rails ransack gem, when using 'sort_link' how can we define an onClick?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

How can we add an onClick attribute to `sort_link`?

```
<%= sort_link @search, :created_at, "Created At" %>
```

I even tried this solution : [Rails 3.2 and Ransack - Is it possible to pass additional params in a sort_link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272095/rails-3-2-and-ransack-is-it-possible-to-pass-additional-params-in-a-sort-link) but it didn't work.

What I really need is to add an `onClick: "return false;"` to make sure the page doesn't scroll to the top every time I click this link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Ransack refresh the page (make a request to the server, replace the markup) which would cause the page to scroll to the top?

I don't think this has anything to do with click handlers..