# Rails ransack sort_link on filtered results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails 5.1 and the Ransack gem.

In my imagecapturings_controller.rb I have a before_action :get_imagecapturings to filter by month and year from a dropdown list:

```
  def get_imagecapturings
    @search = Imagecapturing.ransack(params[:q])
    if params.has_key?(:select)
      if params[:select][:month] == 'all'
        @imagecapturings = Imagecapturing.where("YEAR(datum_anfang) = ?", params[:select][:year])
      else
        @imagecapturings = Imagecapturing.where("MONTH(datum_anfang) = ? AND YEAR(datum_anfang) = ?", params[:select][:month], params[:select][:year])
      end
    else
      @imagecapturings = @search.result
    end
  end
```

And in my view my table head to make it sortable ascending/descending by columns:

```
<th><%= sort_link(@search, :library) %></th>
```

But on the filtered results when a user clicks on the table column header the page is reloaded but the sort on the column header ascending/descending doesn't work.
The decoded URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/?q[s]=library desc&select[month]=12&select[year]=2017&submit=Filter&utf8=✓
```

The sort by asc/desc works only for unfiltered results if the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3001/?method=get&q[s]=library asc
```

My attempt to chain ransack(params[:q]) on the result list doesn't sort:

```
@imagecapturings = Imagecapturing.where("YEAR(datum_anfang) = ?", params[:select][:year])
@search = @imagecapturings.ransack(params[:q])
```

In [Rails 3.2 and Ransack - Is it possible to pass additional params in a sort_link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272095/rails-3-2-and-ransack-is-it-possible-to-pass-additional-params-in-a-sort-link)

a user suggests to add additional params into sort_link and I tried it with:

```
<th><%= sort_link(@search, :library, {:year => params[:select][:year], :month => params[:select][:month]}) %></th>
```

But it doesn't sort.

How can I modify my get_imagecapturings method and/or ransack's sort_link helper in view to make it sortable on filtered results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your exact code, your not returning the `@search.result` in the `if params.has_key?(:select)` statement. Your also not chaining your query with ransack. Try something like:

```
@search = Imagecapturing.ransack(params[:q])
query = @search.result

if params.has_key?(:select)
  if params[:select][:month] == 'all'
    @imagecapturings = query.where("YEAR(datum_anfang) = ?", params[:select][:year])
  else
    @imagecapturings = query.where("MONTH(datum_anfang) = ? AND YEAR(datum_anfang) = ?", params[:select][:month], params[:select][:year])
  end
end
```

I'd probably be inclined to try using some custom ransackers so you don't have to do custom view code and can stick with ransack entirely https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers there's some examples of converting dates like your doing.